# How to duplicate a column?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a data out3 looking like this:

```
ENSG00000133789 11 9554976
ENSG00000131626 11 70272382
ENSG00000020922 11 94324686
ENSG00000102710 13 36925520
...
```

I would like to duplicate the 3rd column and get this:

```
ENSG00000133789 11 9554976 9554976
ENSG00000131626 11 70272382 70272382
ENSG00000020922 11 94324686 94324686
ENSG00000102710 13 36925520 36925520
...
```

I tried doing this:

```
cat out3 | awk '{ $3=$4; print; }'
```

but I got:

```
ENSG00000133789 11 
ENSG00000131626 11 
ENSG00000020922 11 
ENSG00000102710 13 
...
```

My columns are space separated. How do I make this work?

EDIT:

I solved it via:

```
awk -F' ' '{print $0" "$3}' out3 > out4
```

Comment: You have 3 fields per line in your original file, your awk set field 3 equal to field 4. But the latter does not exist and is thus empty, so you actually cleared field 3. You should have set field 4 equal to field 3 (`$4=$3`)

Comment: `awk '{print $0, $3}' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '$4=$3' out3
```

Is all that's necessary. Note that `awk` accepts its input from STDIN and hence piping to `awk` from a `cat` is wasteful of a process and superfluous.  `print` is the default `awk` action, so it can be omitted for brevity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Be aware that this will fail to print a line if `$3` equals to `0`. The solution of [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332387/how-to-duplicate-a-column#comment95483083_54332387) and [karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54332698/8344060) are more robust to this problem.

Comment: Do not do this!

Answer (score 8):

in general, to duplicate the last column

```
$ awk '{print $0,$NF}' file
```